# Neo4j Get All Properties IFF Relationship 'Met' Exists, Partial Properties Otherwise

Tags: node.js, graph, neo4j, cypher

I am still learning Neo4j and using the browser console with REST transactions to perform queries. I have a question on how to accomplish a particular task. Given the following scenario how would one go about completing the following:

- I have 3 users in the database
- 2 users are connected with a relationship `:Met` label.
- The 3rd user does not have any relationship connections

I want to be able to create a Cypher query to do the following:

- IFF a `:Met` relationship exists between the user with whom we are making the query context and the desired user, return all of the properties for the desired user.
- If no relationship exists between the user with whom we are making the query context and the desired user, only return back a public subset of data (avatar, first name, etc.)

Is there a way to execute a single query which can check if this relationship connection exists, return all User information? And if not, return only a subset of properties?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this query, `p1` is the "query context", and `p2` is all other people. A `result` row will only have the `bar` property if `p1` and `p2` have met.

```
MATCH (p1:Person { name: 'Fred' }),(p2:Person)
USING INDEX p1:Person(name)
WHERE p1 <> p2
RETURN
  CASE WHEN (p1)-[:Met]-(p2)
    THEN { name: p2.name, foo: p2.foo, bar: p2.bar }
    ELSE { name: p2.name, foo: p2.foo }
  END AS result;
```

For efficiency, this query assumes that you have first [created an index](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html#schema-index-create-an-index) on `:Person(name)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this whereby you match the first person and then optionally match the second person connected to the first via the `:MET` relationship.  If the relationship exists then the results set you return could have more sensitive data in it.

```
match (p1:Person {name: '1'})
with p1
optional match (p1)-[r:MET]->(p2:Person {name: '2'})
with p1, case when r is not null then
  { name: p1.name, birthday: p1.birthday }
else
  { name: p1.name }
end as data
return data
```

**EDIT:**

OR maybe this is a better fit instead. Match both users and if a relationship exists return more data for the second person.

```
match (p1:Person {name: '1'}), (p2:Person {name: '2'})
with p1, p2
optional match (p1)-[r:MET]->(p2)
with p2, case when r is not null then
  { name: p2.name, birthday: p2.birthday }
else
  { name: p2.name }
end as data
return data
```